# debian repo: Is there a way to include a complete URI for the download path in the Packages.gz file?

Tags: repository, debian

I have several DEBIAN repositories I would like to "virtually" consolidate i.e. have one location for the Packages.gz file whilst having the "download links" for each package listed be located somewhere else (not the same server).

Is this possible?

**Example:**

- Repositories X, Y, Z
- Virtual Repository V with Packages.gz entries

  - X1, X2 etc.
  - Y1, Y2 etc.

**Implementation Suggestion**

Assuming apt-get support it, I intend to write a Google AppEngine application that would fetch on a regular basis the Packages.gz files from the source repositories and *consolidate* them in one repository *V*.

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge, apt and the repo tools do not support it.

But the standard way around it is to use NFS, maybe autofs, and symlinks -- you can always make remote files appear to be local.